# Is there a way to to autoformat a row in DevExpress GridView winforms?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, autoformatting

I have a DevExpress GridControl that is bound to a BindingList that has a collection of `foo` objects.

`foo` has the following members:

`string name;` 
and

`int qty;`

(ofc the properties have get/setters and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` )

What I am trying to accomplish is suppose the qty changes to a value < 0.
Is there a way to set up auto-formatting (say row color  = green if qty > 0 and red if its < 0).

Obviously one way is to set up an event that captures every data change and then evaluate against such condition and then format, but I am thinking there should be an easier way?
Any thoughts? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting up [Style Format Conditions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759), which can be done in designer or through code.

To setup in code:

```
var condition1 = new StyleFormatCondition(FormatConditionEnum.Greater, gridColumnQty, null, 0);
condition1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
condition1.ApplyToRow = true;
gridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition1);

var condition2 = new StyleFormatCondition(FormatConditionEnum.Less, gridColumnQty, null, 0);
condition2.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
condition2.ApplyToRow = true;
gridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition2);
```

Comment: Thanks! got it, but now looks like I have another issue. If my grid is skinned (using standard DevX skin like blueprint, for example),  need to add something else there? any ideas?

Comment: @Gregory Grantt I have no problem using skin together with StyleFormatCondition. What issues did you encounter?